# Is aqua-meth-myoglobin (Fe3+) paramagnetic?

Tags: coordination-compounds, iron

Is aqua-meth-myoglobin (Fe3+) paramagnetic?  In this case, the iron has all 6 coordination positions occupied by ligands: 4 nitrogen atoms from the pyrrolic rings that compose the porphyrin, 1 nitrogen atom in the axial position from the imidazolic system of the distal histidine and in the other axial position is water (or OH  - in the case of hyroxy-meth-myoglobin).  Being different ligands, I don't know whether to consider that the ligands are strong or weak field and implicitly I don't know how the configuration of the iron will be after coordination.  My assumption is that it remains with 5 unpaired electrons, if the ligands are weak field.